# MQTT message is not received because of object in object

Tags: c++, json, object, callback, mqtt

Libraries:

```
<PubSubClient.h>
<ESP8266WiFi.h>
"ArduinoJson.h"
```

When I send this JSON, the message is received and I can do things with it:

```
{"topic":"domoticz/out","payload":{"Battery":255,"LastUpdate":"2022-05-13 16:28:39","Level":25,"RSSI":12,"description":"","dtype":"Color Switch","hwid":"3","id":"00082007","idx":7,"name":"test5","nvalue":15,"stype":"RGBWWZ","svalue1":"25","switchType":"Dimmer","unit":1},"qos":1,"retain":false,"_msgid":"5d58bd06fd9025a4"}
```

But when I send this message (with the Color object in the payload object), nothing happens, the message is not received.

```
{"topic":"domoticz/out","payload":{"Battery":255,"Color":{"b":33,"cw":76,"g":77,"m":4,"r":187,"t":179,"ww":180},"LastUpdate":"2022-05-13 16:31:13","Level":37,"RSSI":12,"description":"","dtype":"Color Switch","hwid":"3","id":"00082007","idx":7,"name":"test5","nvalue":15,"stype":"RGBWWZ","svalue1":"37","switchType":"Dimmer","unit":1},"qos":1,"retain":false,"_msgid":"10c972aa25ee323b"}
```

this is the callback function:

```
 void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {
        Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
        Serial.println(topic);
        StaticJsonDocument<1200> doc;
        //Deserialize the JSON document
        // DeserializationError error = 
        deserializeJson(doc, payload);
        int idx = doc["idx"];
        Serial.printf("       Idx: %d",idx);
```

I think this is because there is a Color object in the object. Is there a way to receive this message?

[image: Photo]

edit:
I stripped down the JSON, now a message is received in my Arduino. But still I can't use the Color object variables.

```
{"Color":{"b":107,"cw":76,"g":238,"m":4,"r":227,"t":179,"ww":180},"Level":49,"idx":7,"nvalue":10,"svalue1":"49"}
```

tried:

```
int t = doc["Color.t"];
Serial.printf(" t: %d",t);
```

did not work

Comment: Are you creating your own deserialize? If not, which library are you using? What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: question was all wrong, I`ve updated it

Comment: You need to show your code for the `callback` function and give a much better description than "does not work".

Comment: updated question with callback

Comment: Try `doc["Color"]["t"];`

Comment: yes! This was the solution.

Comment: But why I needed to strip down the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

To access an object inside another you need two steps, hence to "brackets

```
int t = doc["Color"]["t"];
Serial.printf(" t: %d",t);
```